# How to create a Build Completion Trigger after creating YAML

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

Has anyone figured out how to actually 'use the Classic Editor' once you've gone through the effort of creating a YAML pipeline?  I have two YAML pipelines I'm trying to link so pipe A kicks off after a successful completion of pipe B.

According to Microsoft's own documentation:

> Build completion triggers are not yet supported in YAML syntax. After you create your YAML build pipeline, you can use the classic editor to specify a build completion trigger.

If it was a snake, it probably would have bit me, but I'm at a loss where/how/if "use the classic editor" is possible AFTER creating the pipeline in strictly YAML.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-completion-triggers

[image: Microsoft's blurb regarding Build completion triggers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Micorosft provides a new way - pipeline resource:**

In the following example, we have two pipelines - app-ci (the pipeline defined by the YAML snippet) and security-lib-ci (the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource). We want the app-ci pipeline to run automatically every time a new version of the security library is built in the master branch or any releases branch.

```
# this is being defined in app-ci pipeline
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: securitylib   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: security-lib-ci # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master
```

Check here [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) info.

---

Old answer:

When you edit the YAML click on Triggers:

[image]

There add the trigger:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to make note that this is no longer the recommended method. Please see the note in the docs about moving away from the classical build completion approach. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml